# Chrome Webstore Userlicense API behaviour changes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, licensing, chrome-web-store

I have an extension in the webstore which has a free and a paid mode. In the past 2 days the code that is used to check if the user has purchased a license is failing for a number of them. This has gotten so bad that I decided to disable this check and just provide the paid-for functionality to all users.

I use the  https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses
API (see [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/userLicenses/getUserLicense)) to check if the user has paid the license by verifying if the JSON result value for `license.result == true && license.accessLevel == 'FULL'`.

I noticed when adding some additional logging that all requests are succeeding (returning HTTP 200s) , but that some of these are returning `result == false`, with `maxAgeSecs` of 2 seconds instead of `'FREE_TRIAL'`.

Now I'm wondering if in the case where `result == false` I should be retrying the request in 2 seconds. As my code hasn't changed I was wondering if anything has changed on this API, and if anyone else is experiencing problems.

Comment: From what you describe, this seems to be a bug: nothing in the docs would indicate that it's normal. I would [contact Developer Support](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/).

Comment: Thanks, I have just done that. Will post updates if and when they happen.

Comment: I would like to hear an update on this if possible.  I am randomly having many users of my Chrome Extension purchasing it but then not getting a return of FULL license using the Licensing API.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing?